# Flask Session Cookies Expire Almost instantly, Can't Set Samesite Attribte

Tags: python, flask, cookies, session-cookies, flask-session

I a making a web application with a session cookie log in system. When using the cookies they expire within seconds, logging the user out of any service they were in. When I open my app I occasionaly get a warning in the terminal that states `UserWarning: The session cookie domain is an IP address. This may not work as intended in some browsers. Add an entry to your hosts file, for example "localhost.localdomain", and use that instead.` I'm hosting this app on Heroku so I don't think editing my local file would help, but if theres a way to get this to be solved on Heroku that would be great. Another error message I get comes from the console in the website itself, which reads:

> Cookie “session” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None”
> or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “SameSite“
> attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

I set the Session cookie in my web application to:

```
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = tempfile.mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE"] = True
app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE"] = "None"
Session(app)
```

But this didn't solve my problem and both errors keep coming up. If there's any way to manually set SameSite and Secure that would be fantastic. Getting a https connection on Heroku did not work, I don't know why this is happening and it breaks the site, if there's any advice anyone has that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a domain name to access the service (https://domain.xxx/) and not the IP-address (https://123.123.123.213).

To avoid a lot of pain and errors, you should aim to use HTTPS, especially if you want cookies to work properly. Both the **Secure** and **SameSite** attributes requires HTTPS to work properly in most cases. And to get HTTPS to work you need a domain name and a proper certificate.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: I got my website to have a secure connection but this issue still persists, do you know why the cookies keep disappearing?

Comment: The Secure and SameSite alert keep coming up

Comment: What alerts to you get?

Comment: I get the same "Cookie “session” will be soon rejected because it..." from the website console, the weird thing is that it actually isn't that big of a deal because it works 1/2 of the time so if I set the cookie to permanent it will work forever after eventually getting it to work. It's super weird but it's not that big of a deal so thank you for your original help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Flask app ... setting the value to None (i.e. app.config["SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE"] = None) instead of "None" fixed my issue ...